# Merging Two Lists of Tuples

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, merge

I need to create a recursive function that merges two lists of tuples together and it starts with a known tuple. The function receives three parameters:

- two lists of tuples
- a tuple

I've tried this:

```hs
mergePoints l1 l2 o = o ++ [f | (a, b) <- zip l1 l2, 
                                let f if a < b then f = a, b else f = b, a]
```

I know I'm not doing it right, but I really don't know how to do it.

The example input and output for the exercise is:

```
ghci> mergePoints [(1, 3), (1, 4), (5, 5)] [(1, 1), (4, 4)] (0, 0)
[(0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 3.0), (1.0, 4.0), (4.0, 4.0), (5.0, 5.0)]
```

Comment: if it "starts with a known tuple", then simply `mergePoints l1 l2 o = o : mergePoints2 l1 l2`, isn't it?

Comment: *why the dv?* the OP states the problem, shows an attempt at coding a solution, the sample input and the desired output... this is a nearly perfectly asked question, I thought. In fact I should've uv'd it right away. If it's good enough to answer, it's good enough to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example,

```
ghci> mergePoints [(1, 3), (1, 4), (5, 5)] [(1, 1), (4, 4)] 
      (0, 0)
[    (0.0, 0.0),                          (1.0, 1.0), 
               (1.0, 3.0), (1.0, 4.0),            (4.0, 4.0), 
                                  (5.0, 5.0)]
```

each of the two lists is consumed at its own pace, so `zip` won't fit here, as it consumes its argument lists at the same pace.

The simplest way to code this is with a directly recursive definition with pattern matching that will compare the two head elements and use one or the other, depending on the result of the comparison.

Perhaps you will also need to compare them with the supplied third point, in case it's not the smallest.

---

So, about your code.

Judging from the example input and output, the points are supposed to come out in order. We can just compare the tuples as they define a *lexicographical* ordering. You already are doing that. With a small syntactical fix your code is:

```
mergePoints1 l1 l2 o  =  o ++ [f | (a, b) <- zip l1 l2, 
                                   let f if a < b then f = [a, b] 
                                                  else f = [b, a]]
```

This is not a valid Haskell. There is no assignment in Haskell, only definition:

```
mergePoints2 l1 l2 o  =  o ++ [f | (a, b) <- zip l1 l2, 
                                   let f = if a < b then [a, b] else [b, a]]
```

But this list comprehension creates a list of lists of tuples, as we're creating them as either `f = [a,b]` or `f = [b,a]`. Using the points one by one we need to "draw" them from those short lists, one by one, with

```
mergePoints3 l1 l2 o  =  o ++ [r | (a, b) <- zip l1 l2, 
                                   r <- if a < b then [a, b] else [b, a]]
```

(using `r` for "result", instead of `f`). The last error is that `++` concatenates two *lists*, but `o` isn't one. So then it must be

```
mergePoints4 l1 l2 o  =  [o] ++ merge1 l1 l2

merge1 l1 l2  =  [r | (a, b) <- zip l1 l2, 
                      r <- if a < b then [a, b] else [b, a]]
```

Now it works, but doesn't do what it's supposed to. And in fact, since its output is still not guaranteed to be ordered, we could even just write this as

```
merge2 l1 l2  =  l1 ++ l2
  where                     -- the definition of the built-in `++`:
  []     ++ l2  =  l2
  l1     ++ []  =  l1
  (x:t1) ++ l2  =  x : (t1 ++ l2)
```

or we could pull the elements from *both* lists with

```
merge3 l1 l2  =  l1 ++ l2
  where
  []     ++ l2      =  l2
  l1     ++ []      =  l1
  (x:t1) ++ (y:t2)  =  x : y : (t1 ++ t2)   -- or:
               --   =  x : ((y:t2) ++ t1)
```

Of course taking out the elements one by one *positionally* scrambles up their ordering, potentially. Your attempt to rectify this with the `merge1` can be re-written as

```
merge1b l1 l2  =  l1 ++ l2
  where
  []     ++ l2  =  l2
  l1     ++ []  =  l1
  (x:t1) ++ (y:t2)  =  if  x < y  then  x : y : (t1 ++ t2)
                       else             y : x : (t1 ++ t2)
```

but it still can scramble up the order. We *assume* our two inputs to be *ordered*, increasing lists where each element is smaller then the one that follows it in the list. So we just need to use that knowledge, *carefully* pulling just one of the elements:

```
merge4 l1 l2  =  l1 ++ l2
  where
  []     ++ l2      =  l2
  l1     ++ []      =  l1
  (x:t1) ++ (y:t2)  =  if   x < y  then  x : (_ ++ (y:t2))
                       else              _ : _
```

You need to complete this definition by replacing the `_`s with the actual code.

<sub>Bonus question: the usual definition of `merge` in Haskell prefers its "left" argument over the "right" one, in case of equality of the two elements. Make a one-character edit to the code, to achieve this.</sub>

Comment: I understand. The new problem is that I'm not really sure how to do this recursion.

Comment: here's an example: `foo x | x > 10 = [] | otherwise = x : foo (x+1)`.

Comment: here's another: `bar [] = [] ; bar (x:xs) | x > 10 = [] | otherwise = x : bar xs`.

Comment: I ended up with this: `mergePoints [] [] o = [] ; mergePoints (x:xs) (y:ys) o | x <= y = p ++ [x] ++ [y] ++ mergePoints xs ys o | x > y = p ++ [y] ++ [x] ++ mergePoints xs ys o ; where p = o : [] ` , I know where I have the error, I just don't know what to do with it

Comment: you're almost there, just need to pick *just one* of the `[x] ++` *or* `[y] ++` in each case! If you do them both, it's again consuming the two lists at the same speed. also, try first coding this without the `o` at all.

Comment: I actually need to compare and add the first element of the 2 lists at the same time, in order.

Comment: The order in the output is exactly what I want, the problem is the last point, the first one, that I named `o`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201288/discussion-between-mariana-leites-and-will-ness).

Comment: I got it to work, another way. What I first wanted to do is what you did in mergePoints2, but I was getting errors in the let clause, so what you did helped me understand my error and now I know how to work it.
All the rest is a really good help for me to understand a bit more of Haskell and how it works. Thank you very much, this is a really good help.

Comment: you're very welcome, it's good to see someone asking a question properly and staying engaged with it. :)